# Furnace won't turn back on after leaking collector box diagnosed

Tags: furnace

We had water leaking from under our furnace, so we called our an HVAC repair company.  Their tech opened up the furnace and determined that we have a leaky collector box.  He ordered he replacement part, and let us know that it would be here in a few days.

Right before leaving he told me that after he left I should use my Shop-Vac to suction out the standing water and then close up the two access panels, which he had left open.  He said that the furnace would not work while the access panels were open, but when I closed them up the furnace should turn on automatically.

You can probably guess where this is going...  He left, I Shop-Vacced out the water, closed up both access panels, and — nothing.  No heat.

This was Friday afternoon, just before close of business, and we figured that rather than pay for an emergency call we could make do over the weekend with space heaters and sweaters.  It's now Monday morning and I've spoken to their office, who say "Until the replacement part is installed, it's not safe to run the furnace."  This completely contradicts what the tech told me before he left.

Just to be completely clear, the furnace was working fine before the tech came -- the water was annoying and a source of concern, but didn't interfere with function.  And as far as I can tell the technician didn't do anything other than open the panels and diagnose the problem.

Any thoughts on why the furnace won't turn on, and what I can do about it?  It could be a few more days before the part comes in, and it's pretty cold in here.

Comment: He may have done something to prevent the furnace from starting up while he was working.  Perhaps a simple as a master cutoff switch, circuit breaker, ignitor power switch, or perhaps a disconnected wire.      It is true that with a leaking collector there is danger of some flue gas entering the living space.    If you don't have a CO detector in the area  it would be a good idea to keep it off.

Comment: When you turn the furnace on, do you hear any clicks (attempted ignition) or see any indicator lights? Or does it do absolutely nothing at all?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Nothing happens at all.

Comment: Then it *likely* is one of the things jay613 mentioned - either a master cutoff switch or circuit breaker. But it is possible he disconnected something (and forgot to put it back in) or that there was something loose and when vacuuming up the water some wire came out.